# Why does this Batch file fail to change the wallpaper (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7

I have a script that runs (without error) to change the desktop wallpaper. The only problem is that it doesn't change the wallpaper. The registry entry is changed appropriately, so that bits working. Just the reloading is not working.

```
:: Configure Wallpaper
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V Wallpaper /T REG_SZ /F /D "C:\Users\greynolds\AppData\Roaming\APOD Wallpaper\apod_wallpaper1.png"
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V WallpaperStyle /T REG_SZ /F /D 0
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V TileWallpaper /T REG_SZ /F /D 2
:: Make the changes effective immediately
%SystemRoot%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UpdatePerUserSystemParameters is a undocumented function AFAIK

[ReactOS defines it](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/893a3c9d030fd8b078cbd747eeefd3f6ce57e560/win32ss/user/user32/misc/logon.c#L99) as: BOOL WINAPI UpdatePerUserSystemParameters(DWORD dwReserved,BOOL Enable)

[That function definition means that it is **not** a function you can call with RunDll32](https://web.archive.org/web/1999/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx) (You end up passing random parameters to the function)

Comment: Thanks for that! Any idea how I might be able to get the result I want? It's very frustrating as it works *sometimes* and all the forums etc. say that this is the way to do it.

Comment: @Greg: Most of the time someone has code that uses RunDll32, it is wrong! Very few functions are designed to be used by RunDll32.

Comment: I just looked at the list of scriptable shell objects (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776890) and did not find anything that could be called from windows scripting host, so your only option is to use a external program or possibly a powershell script that uses the IActiveDesktop COM object...

Comment: Thanks for your help - I am really new to Windows scripting. I think the external program looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here how you call this function but better to use documented API:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1 True
```

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing (in my experience) setting up `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop` more often would not work.

The best solution is to call win32 api function `SystemParametersInfoSetWallpaper` - it works every time. I found this powershell module/snippet to be quite helpful https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Change-window-borderdesktop-609a6fb2