# Speeding up a Powershell script to change my wallpaper background

Tags: powershell

So I made a powershell script to change my wallpaper background. Code is posted below. I binded the script to a hotkey on my laptop.

The problem is when I hit the hotkey it has a delay to open the powershell and then changes the background. Takes 2-3 seconds for the wallpaper to change. It also only works about 75% of the time (hence the repeated lines 4 to 15).

I have a bash script in my linux environment that is immediate. I'm hoping to get the same behavior in windows. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Function Set-WallPaper($Value)
{
 Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -name wallpaper -value $value
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
}

$pictures_path = "C:\Users\mcdonago\Pictures\wallpapers-master\wallpapers-master\Wallpapers\"
$pictures = Get-ChildItem -File -path $pictures_path
$random_num = Get-Random -Maximum $pictures.Count
$new_wallpaper = [string]$pictures[$random_num]
$wallpaper_str = $pictures_path + $new_wallpaper
Write-Host $wallpaper_str
Set-Wallpaper($wallpaper_str)
```

Edit: Would also be open to third party applications that help me achieve my goal (hit a hotkey to immediately change my background)

Comment: Script wise, you won't be able to speed anything up, it is running as fast as it can. What you are running into is that you are at the mercy of the speed that Windows takes to update the background. (e.g. loading the new file into memory, and what takes time is the "smooth" transition effects to switch). Linux is completely different, and you can't compare the change speed between the two.

Comment: Technically, you can just specify:  `$wallpaper_str = (Get-ChildItem -File -path $pictures_path | Get-Random).FullName` which eliminates about 6 lines of code.  However, @HAL9256 is correct.  Your limitation is Windows, not your PowerShell code.  That said, I believe the correct command is `rundll32.exe user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True`.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Your main problem is that the [UpdatePerUserSystemParameters function is not intended to be called from rundll32 in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018828/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this Batch file fail to change the wallpaper (Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018828/why-does-this-batch-file-fail-to-change-the-wallpaper-windows-7)

Comment: Your script can technically be made faster: `Get-Random ([System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($pictures_path))` should be minutely faster, what with not making and decorating objects for all the files when you just want a full filename, and not invoking a pipeline. If you knew how many pictures there were, and there were a lot, you could avoid enumerating all of them with `get-childitem | select -first 1 -skip (get-random -min 1 -max $N)` and on average only have to enumerate half of them .. (but it's not the slowest part so that won't help).

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that you should not be trying to use `rundll32.exe` to change the wallpaper image, because the `UpdatePerUserSystemParameters` function is not designed to be called from `rundll32.exe` in the first place.

[Raymond Chen talked about this at length, already, some time ago.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043)

The function signature required by `rundll32.exe` is [documented](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/164787/), and the `UpdatePerUserSystemParameters` function does not use that function signature.

First, the`UpdatePerUserSystemParameters` function isn't even officially listed in the Windows API documentation (at least, not at the time I write this). Aside from the fact that this suggests that the function is not for public use, there's not a way to officially verify whether its function signature is compatible with `rundll32.exe`.

Second, even when you can find a definition of the function's signature (such as [the one in reactos noted by Anders in question 5018828](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018828/)), the signature does not match the one required by `rundll32.exe`.

TL;DR: Don't use `rundll32.exe` to try to execute the `UpdatePerUserSystemParameters` from `user32.dll`. Doing so is not guaranteed to work and in fact may even exhibit strange behaviors. (In particular, I would not recommend pathologically executing it multiple times in the hope that it will somehow work "better.")

Comment: Then how would you recommend changing the wallpaper through the command line

Comment: Search for, and call, the correct Windows API. If you're not versed in that, it's likely someone has already written a command-line tool for it. Or alternatively, use Group Policy, which is good at making these kinds of changes.

Answer (score -1):

The script can't be made faster. I am limited by the Windows OS.